# Identifying elements of $\Bbb Z$ in the language $\{+,*,-,<,0,1\}$

Tags: logic

$L$ is the language $\{+,*, -, <,0, 1\}$. I need help showing that for each $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ there is an atomic $L$-formula $F_{m}(x)$, having $x$ as its only variable, that defines the one-element subsets ${m}$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ i.e. $\{a \in \mathbb{Z}: F_{m}(a)\} = \{m\}$.

I know that an atomic formula is with no connectors and an $L$-formula is a pair $(A,I)$ where $I$ is an interpretation of $A$ on $L$. I'm confused why this formula $F_{m}$. Not sure where to go from here.

Then I can use that proof to show that for each finite subset $Y= \{m_1,...,m_k\}$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ there is an $L$ formula $F_{Y}(x)$ that defines $Y$, i.e. $F_{Y}(a)$ if true iff $a \in Y$ I think. I'm just stuck on how to go about it.

Comment: m = 0 + 1 + 1 + ... + 1 m times.

Answer (score 2):

For $m \ge 0$ let $F_m(x)$ be given by:

$$x = 0 + \underbrace{1+\ldots+1}_{\text{$m$ ones}}$$

For $m < 0$, let $F_m(x)$ be given by:

$$x = 0 - \underbrace{(1+\ldots+1)}_{\text{$m$ ones}}$$

For $F_Y(x)$, we simply take:

$$\bigvee_{m \in Y} F_m(x)$$